# Line Reading Bug in Fortran

Tags: format, fortran

I am writing Fortran code in order to read a list of reactions along with their reaction type. The list is in a file named reactions.rx that looks like this:

```
H2O       O1D       OH        OH                2BODY                  .  
               .  
               .  (Same format continued)
               .  
CH3C2H    HV        C3H3      H                 PHOTO  
CH3C2H    HV        C3H2      H2                PHOTO  
CH3C2H    HV        CH3       C2H               PHOTO  
CH2CCH2   HV        C3H3      H                 PHOTO  
CH2CCH2   HV        C3H2      H2                PHOTO  
CH2CCH2   HV        C2H2      CH23              PHOTO  
C2H6      HV        CH23      CH23      H2      PHOTO  
C2H6      HV        CH4       CH21              PHOTO  
C2H6      HV        C2H2      H2        H2      PHOTO  
C2H6      HV        C2H4      H         H       PHOTO  
C2H6      HV        C2H4      H2                PHOTO  
C2H6      HV        CH3       CH3               PHOTO  
C2H       C2H2      HCAER     H                 2BODY  
C2H       CH2CCH2   HCAER2    H                 2BODY
```

The goal is to write code such that it finds the first occurrence of a designated species in the left most column that has the label PHOTO, then continue to read the file until the line no longer contains the species or isn't PHOTO.

My code so far:

```
! reactions.rx is opened earlier as file 12
667   FORMAT(A10, A10, A10, A10, A8, A5)

      stat = 0
      ! Reads until a line is found in reactions.rx with reactant1 == species 
      ! and label beginning with "PHOT"
      do while((trim(reac1).ne.trim(species).OR.label(1:4).ne.'PHOT')
     &  .AND.stat == 0)
        READ(12,667,IOSTAT=stat) reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,label
      end do

      if(stat.ne.0) then
        print*, " *** Species not in reactions.rx!!!! *** "
        STOP
      endif

     ! reac1...prod3,label hold the first line of matching info
     ! Does some work ...

     ! Continue reading the file until the line is no longer about a PHOT
     ! reaction beginning with species
     do while(trim(reac1).eq.trim(species).AND.
    &    label(1:4).eq.'PHOT')
       if(label(5:5).ne.'O') then
         ! Does some work ...    
       else
         ! Does some work ...
         ! The following print statements are for testing purposes
         print*, "AT SPECIES: ", species
         print*, "ON LINE: ", reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,label
       endif
       stat = 0       
       READ(12, 667, IOSTAT=stat) reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,
    &        label
       print*, "NEXT LINE: ",reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,label,
    &        stat          
       if(stat.ne.0) then
         label = 'DONE ' !breaks while
       endif
     enddo
     close(12)
```

With this code I get the output:(forgive the poor formatting)

```
 AT SPECIES: H2O
 ON LINE: H2O       HV        H         OH                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: O3        HV        O2        O1D                 PHOTP                    0
 AT SPECIES: CO2
 ON LINE: CO2       HV        CO        O                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CO2       HV        CO        O1D                 PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: CO2
 ON LINE: CO2       HV        CO        O1D                 PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CO        OH        CO2       H                   WEIRD                    0
 AT SPECIES: H2CO
 ON LINE: H2CO      HV        H2        CO                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: H2CO      HV        HCO       H                   PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: H2CO
 ON LINE: H2CO      HV        HCO       H                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: HCO       HV        H         CO                  2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH4
 ON LINE: CH4       HV        CH21      H2                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH4       HV        CH3       H                   PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH4
 ON LINE: CH4       HV        CH3       H                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH4       HV        CH23      H         H         PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH4
 ON LINE: CH4       HV        CH23      H         H         PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C         OH        CO        H                   2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH
 ON LINE: CH        HV        C         H                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH        S         CS        H                   2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH2CO
 ON LINE: CH2CO     HV        CH23      CO                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH23      CO        CH2CO                         WEIRD                    0
 AT SPECIES: C2H2
 ON LINE: C2H2      HV        C2H       H                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C2H2      HV        C2        H2                  PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C2H2
 ON LINE: C2H2      HV        C2        H2                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C2H2      OH        CO        CH3                 2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: C2H4
 ON LINE: C2H4      HV        C2H2      H2                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C2H4      HV        C2H2      H         H         PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C2H4
 ON LINE: C2H4      HV        C2H2      H         H         PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH23      CH3       C2H4      H                   2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH3CHO
 ON LINE: CH3CHO    HV        CH3       HCO                 PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH3CHO    HV        CH4       CO                  PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH3CHO
 ON LINE: CH3CHO    HV        CH4       CO                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C2H5      CH3       C3H8                          WEIRD                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H8
 ON LINE: C3H8      HV        C3H6      H2                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C3H8      HV        C2H6      CH21                PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H8
 ON LINE: C3H8      HV        C2H6      CH21                PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C3H8      HV        C2H4      CH4                 PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H8
 ON LINE: C3H8      HV        C2H4      CH4                 PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C3H8      HV        C2H5      CH3                 PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H8
 ON LINE: C3H8      HV        C2H5      CH3                 PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C2H       C3H8      C2H2      C3H7                2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H6
 ON LINE: C3H6      HV        C2H2      CH3       H         PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C3H6      HV        CH2CCH2   H2                  PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H6
 ON LINE: C3H6      HV        CH2CCH2   H2                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C3H6      HV        C2H4      CH23                PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H6
 ON LINE: C3H6      HV        C2H4      CH23                PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C3H6      HV        C2H       CH4       H         PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H6
 ON LINE: C3H6      HV        C2H       CH4       H         PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C2H5CHO   HV        C2H5      HCO                 PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C2H5CHO
 ON LINE: C2H5CHO   HV        C2H5      HCO                 PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: H2O       O1D       OH        OH                  2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: C3H3
 ON LINE: C3H3      HV        C3H2      H                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH3C2H    HV        C3H3      H                   PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH3C2H
 ON LINE: CH3C2H    HV        C3H3      H                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: H2O       O1D       OH        OH                  2BODY                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH2CCH2
 ON LINE: CH2CCH2   HV        C3H3      H                   PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH2CCH2   HV        C3H2      H2                  PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH2CCH2
 ON LINE: CH2CCH2   HV        C3H2      H2                  PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: CH2CCH2   HV        C2H2      CH23                PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: CH2CCH2
 ON LINE: CH2CCH2   HV        C2H2      CH23                PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: C2H6      HV        CH23      CH23      H2        PHOTO                    0
 AT SPECIES: C2H6
 ON LINE: C2H6      HV        CH23      CH23      H2        PHOTO
 NEXT LINE: H2O       O1D       OH        OH                  2BODY                    0
```

For a little clarification, AT SPECIES: tells which species I am matching to reac1. ON LINE prints the line info that matched the requirements (species and PHOT). NEXT LINE prints the line that gets read in next.

My bug first appears at species CH3C2H. As you can see from the output, one reaction line of CH3C2H gets read (15 lines up from bottom of output) as it should. However the NEXT LINE is printed as "H2O       O1D       OH        OH                  2BODY". The next line in reactions.rx (which should be getting read) is pretty clearly "CH3C2H    HV        C3H2      H2                PHOTO". This is a reaction I'm interested in, but for some reason the line read is instead the very first line of reactions.rx. The same issue occurs for C2H6 (lastly in output). For this species 5 more lines should be read in from reactions.rx, but again after the first line NEXT LINE becomes H2O....2BODY. The H2O line ends the do loop rightfully so, my issue is that I don't understand why in these two cases the wrong line is read.

While in some cases where I commented "! does some work..." there is more code, as you can see the actual print and read statements I'm interested in have no other code between them. Because of this, I do not believe it's an issue with variables/storage, it seems to be some kind of error either with my loop or the actual read. I am confident that the correct file (reactions.rx) is being read. I've even made changes to it and printed the whole thing out in the code to ensure that it is the file being read.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this bug happens, especially since the code does exactly what it is intended to do for every other species aside from the two discussed above. Any help or suggestions people can offer would be greatly appreciated.

I am compiling with gfortran 5.3.0 on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: *As you can see from the output*  Not really.  Why not write out a neat table organised like your input file; that would make it much easier for me (possibly even you) to see where and how things go wrong.

Comment: I guess... `! Does some work` reopens the file or repositions unit `12`.  What happens when you trace execution in a debugger?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark you're right I should probably take some time to actually format the output. I have other obligations for the remainder of my day but I'll try to update my post tomorrow.

Comment: @IanH I've looked over the code several times and 12 is not reopened or opened as something different. What debugger would you recommend using? I currently do my coding in Sublime 3 and use cygwin to compile/run.

Comment: I took your code and compiled it. It seems to work fine, though I noticed that there are inconsistencies in the indentation. So I agree with @IanH that the issue is probably somewhere in the `! Does some work` area.

Comment: @chw21 Could you post your version of the code? I've been systematically commenting out the sections of code labeled "! does some work" and have yet to see a change in my output

Answer (score 1):

You asked me for "my version of the code" in the comments to your question.
What I've done is to turn your code into a subroutine which I then call with

```
CALL READ_REACTIONS(species)
```

So first, here's your code, minimally modified:

```
      SUBROUTINE READ_REACTIONS(species)
        implicit none
        character(len=10) :: species
        character(len=10) :: reac1, reac2, prod1, prod2
        character(len=8) :: prod3
        character(len=5) :: label
        integer stat

        PRINT *, "Searching for species " // species

        OPEN(12, file="reactions.rx", action="READ")
  667   FORMAT(A10, A10, A10, A10, A8, A5)

      stat = 0
      ! Reads until a line is found in reactions.rx with reactant1 == species
      ! and label beginning with "PHOT"
      do while((trim(reac1).ne.trim(species).OR.label(1:4).ne.'PHOT')
     &  .AND.stat == 0)
        READ(12,667,IOSTAT=stat) reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,label
      end do

      if(stat.ne.0) then
        print*, " *** Species not in reactions.rx!!!! *** "
        GOTO 999 ! < You had a STOP here, but I'd rather make a clean
                 ! exit including the CLOSE
      endif

      ! reac1...prod3,label hold the first line of matching info
      ! Does some work ...

      ! Continue reading the file until the line is no longer about a PHOT
      ! reaction beginning with species
      do while(trim(reac1).eq.trim(species).AND.
     &    label(1:4).eq.'PHOT')
        if(label(5:5).ne.'O') then
          ! Does some work ...
        else
          ! Does some work ...
          ! The following print statements are for testing purposes
          print*, "AT SPECIES: ", species
          print*, "ON LINE: ", reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,label
        endif
        stat = 0
        READ(12, 667, IOSTAT=stat) reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,
     &        label
        print*, "NEXT LINE: ",reac1,reac2,prod1,prod2,prod3,label,
     &        stat
        if(stat.ne.0) then
          label = 'DONE ' !breaks while
        endif
      enddo
 999  CONTINUE   ! <-- added label for the clean exit if species not found.
      close(12)
      END SUBROUTINE READ_REACTIONS
```

As you can see, I only added the declaration block and the `OPEN` statement, and changed your `STOP` to a `GOTO` to just before it closes the file.

I don't have your full `reactions.rx`, but with the snippet that you offered, it works fine.

I have also created my own version of the `read_reactions` which I think is a bit easier to read. I wrapped the whole thing up in a module so that I don't need to declare an explicit interface. In real code I'd actually make better error handling, but this post is already too long.

```
module mod_read_reactions

  implicit none
  character(len=*), parameter :: fmt = "(4(A10), A8, A5)"
  character(len=*), parameter :: file_name = 'reactions.rx'
contains
  subroutine read_reactions(species)
    implicit none
    character(len=10), intent(in) :: species
    integer :: iounit, ios
    character(len=200) :: iomsg
    character(len=10) :: reac1, reac2, prod1, prod2
    character(len=8) :: prod3
    character(len=5) :: label

    open( newunit=iounit, file=file_name, iostat=ios, &
          iomsg=iomsg, status="old", action="read" )
    if ( ios /= 0 ) stop "Error opening file " ! Suggest better error handling

    searchloop : do
      read(iounit, fmt, iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg)  &
            reac1, reac2, prod1, prod2, prod3, label
      if (ios /= 0) then
        print *, "Species " // trim(species) // " not found."
        goto 999
      end if

      if (reac1 == species .and. label == "PHOTO") exit searchloop
    end do searchloop

    do while (ios == 0 .and. reac1 == species .and. label == 'PHOTO')
      ! When we come in here, we should already have the first match, so we can
      ! immediately act upon it (in this case just print it out)
      print *, reac1, reac2, prod1, prod2, prod3, label

      ! Now read the next line.
      read(iounit, fmt, iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg)  &
            reac1, reac2, prod1, prod2, prod3, label
    end do

999 continue
    close(iounit)
  end subroutine read_reactions

end module mod_read_reactions
```

I should add that this code is still re-opening and closing the file for each new species request, which isn't too smart.